# Woocommerce display one random product via php

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to display one random product in my template header. So each time someone visits or refresh there will be a different product displayed in the header.

I searched and found this

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[products ids="1, 2, 3, 4, 5"]');
?>
```

But this only displays products which have ids mentioned in this call. Is there anyway to get one random product?

Comment: As far as I know WC has no shortcode for random product(s), so you'd have to do your own. But why don't you take a look at the woocommerce docs for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could treat products like any other post type and query using [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).  Limit the number of posts retrieved to 1 and change the orderby parameter to random:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'post_type'        => 'product' ); 

$random_products = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You could also use new [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) which would be similar.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. How do I get product image and price with this method?

Comment: The product image is just the featured image, so you'd show that the same as other post types: [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).  Price is a little different. At its base though all the price info is stored as post meta which can be retrieved with `get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', true );`. Going into more WooCommerce-specific options is off-topic. Take a look at the WC shortcodes/templates for an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of code I am using for mine its for recent products but is doing the job. Just add to page you want to show them on.

```
[recent_products per_page="4" columns="4" orderby="rand" order="rand"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Random Products Widget for WooCommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Widget_Random_Products.html) which you can add to a header widget area.